# require.js is not loading any modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to load a module using require.js, and I have the following in my app.js:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "js"
});


alert("hello world"); // for debugging

require(['eh2'], function(eh2) {
    alert("nothing here"); // for debugging
});
```

When I run my application, though, despite the app.js being loaded, the module I'm requiring is never loaded - the "hello world" executes, but the "nothing here" doesn't!

My script tag in the HTML page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/require.js" data-main="app"></script>
```

And eh2.js is located in the js folder, and it is wrapped in a define statement:

```
define(["./screens/Screens"], function(screens) {
    return {
        // code here
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is require.js silently failing on loading some submodule under screens.js, perhaps?

Here is the code from the Screens module:

```
    define([ "screens/TitleScreen", "screens/GameScreen" ], function(titleScreen, gameScreen) {
    return {

        screenFuncs: {
            "TitleScreen" : titleScreen.TitleScreen,
            "GameScreen" : gameScreen.GameScreen,
        },

        buildScreen: function(data) {
            var func = screenFuncs[data.type];
            var screen = new func(data.params);
            return screen;
        },
    };
});
```

Do the paths in the define call need to be relative to the current location of the js file I'm in, or to the root defined in the app.js, anyway?

Comment: Any errors on chrome console or firebug ?

Comment: try `define("eh2", ["./screens/Screens"], …);`. Also check whether the screens-script is loaded correctly - have a look at your network panel

Comment: require.js won't normally fail silently, you'll get errors (they may be delayed sometimes).  Make sure to also turn on asynchronous request logging in whatever browser debug tool you're using.

Comment: There is an error in the Screens module on the console, actually - but it's the same sort of thing: it can't find the code in the module I'm loading there. Since there's no formatting allowed in comments, I'll edit the original post to include the code from Screens.

Comment: And yes, I tried it without the namespace prefixes on the constructor names, and everything did work before I separated it out into multiple js files and used require!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this:

```
define(["./screens/Screens"], function(screens) {
    ....
});
```

either with an absolut path variant:

```
define(["screens/Screens"], function(screens) {
    ....
});
```

or use:

```
define(function(require) {
    var screens = require("./screens/Screens");
    ....
});
```

---

From the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes):

> **Relative module names inside define():**
>
> For require("./relative/name")
>   calls that can happen inside a define() function call, be sure to ask
>   for "require" as a dependency, so that the relative name is resolved
>   correctly:

```
define(["require", "./relative/name"], function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

> Or better yet, use the shortened syntax that is available for use with translating CommonJS
>   modules:

```
define(function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've still got something wrong in my app.js - the "nothing here" never appears, so it's not even loading my main eh2.js file!

Comment: Hmm, I think my problem may actually be that I created a class called Screen, which is getting overridden by the browser's Screen object! I'll try renaming it...

Comment: It's maybe not even loading your eh2.js file because this is the file with the wrong definition I mentioned above..!

Comment: Well, I did get it to load eh2.js by fixing the issues you'd suggested, but all the other files eh2.js depends on in turn depend on Screen.js, so maybe require("Screen") was failing silently because Screen was already defined?

Comment: If you require("Screen") it will never conflict with a global `screen` or `Screen`. Define and require (concerning the module names) build their own scope that can't conflict with the global browser scope..